# Content visibility based on multiple url values with strstr?

Tags: php, wordpress

Using a Wordpress plugin to sort custom post types based on custom taxonomies. Results are returned on the post type's archive page. Sorting is working great but hit a snag trying to display header content for items with multiple taxonomies:

```
<?php if(strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "level/invigorating")) { ?>
 <h3>These poses are invigorating:</h3>
<?php } ?>

<?php if(strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "level/invigorating/position/seated")) { ?>
 <h3>These poses are invigorating and seated:</h3>
 <p>For positions of this nature please take care of your sacrum.</p>
<?php } ?>

<?php if(strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "position/seated")) { ?>
 <h3>These poses are seated:</h3>
<?php } ?>
```

`"level/invigorating/position/seated"` returns three `h3`'s because all `if`'s return true.

My PHP skills are awful and trying to understand the manual is like staring into the night sky.

How can this be written so only one value can be returned per page?

Perhaps [this screenshot](http://imgur.com/KPZKjiW) helps.

Using [Beautiful Taxonomy Filters](https://github.com/jonathan-dejong/beautiful-taxonomy-filters).

Comment: I don't know if i understand this problem right but I would suggest to make use of the wordpress hierarchy for custom post type https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png

Comment: Thanks! I believe templates are working fine. I probably could have left out all the bits about post types and taxonomies but I wanted to explain the urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to do is this...

```
<?php if(strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "level/invigorating/position/seated")) { ?>
 <h3>These poses are invigorating and seated:</h3>
 <p>For positions of this nature please take care of your sacrum.</p>
<?php } elseif(strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "level/invigorating")) { ?>
 <h3>These poses are invigorating:</h3>
<?php } elseif(strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "position/seated")) { ?>
 <h3>These poses are seated:</h3>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's how I pictured it working but couldn't make it happen. Much appreciated kind sir.